# Combine two json files and iterate over them

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, rails-api

I have two json files (info.json and images.json) in my Rails root directory. They are both an extraction from a web scraping project I have and which I've been doing with the Mechanize Gem.

So I have two Json files, one has info about Plants like this:

**info.json**

```
{
  "Brazil":[
  {"Jungle Plants":[bla bla bla ]},
  {"Desert Plants":[ bla bla bla ]}],

  "Egypt":[
  {"Jungle Plants":[bla bla bla ]},
  {"Desert Plants":[ bla bla bla ]}]
  
  and so on...
}
```

And the other Json file has the images the country flags like this:

**images.json**

```
{
   "images":
      {
        "Brazil":"link/to/flag_image.jpg", 
        "Egypt":"link/to/flag_image.jpg",
        
         and so on...
      }
}
```

**My migration table:**

```
class CreatePlants < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :plants do |t|
      t.string :country_name
      t.jsonb :plant_categories
      t.string :flag_photo

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

**What I currently have:**

```
json_file = File.open("#{Rails.root}/info.json").read
json_objects = JSON.parse(json_file).symbolize_keys

json_objects.each { |key, value| Plants.create!(country_name: key, plant_categories: value) }
```

In my seeds, how can I combine both JSON files and make them pair/match with the respective image flag and their data and save them in the DB?
I will appreciate your help!

EDIT: The flag images are download in the same order as the info.json country information. I would like to know how can I combine both of the files and save them in the DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below should work:

```
info = JSON.parse(File.read("#{Rails.root}/info.json"))
images = JSON.parse(File.read("#{Rails.root}/images.json"))


info.each do |country_name, plants|
  # Hope the Model name is singular here
  plant = Plant.new(country_name: country_name, plant_categories: plants)
  path = images['images'][country_name]
  if path
    # Read the file from remote URL like S3
    # images['images'][country_name] - Will return the image URL on the key country_name
    attachment = open(images['images'][country_name])
    plant.flag_photo = attachment
  end
  plant.save!
end
```

Comment: When I run my seed I get:
`NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
`
any idea why?

Comment: Can you please share backtrace of the exception

Comment: Are you using symbols as keys on the line `file = open(images['images'][country_name])` like `file = open(images[:images][country_name])` ?

Comment: Ok yes I was missing that part - Now when I run the migration I get:

`TypeError: no implicit conversion of nil into String
/Users/thekid/Documents/plants_api/db/seeds.rb:13:in block in <top (required)>'
/Users/thekid/Documents/plants_api/db/seeds.rb:10:in each'
/Users/thekid/Documents/plants_api/db/seeds.rb:10:in <top (required)>'`

Comment: Is there any possibilities of file URL can be empty for a country on images.json?

Comment: Yes in some, the mechanize gem cannot find some images and therefore is passes it as an empty array. Do you think that can be an issue?

Comment: Yes, The URL returned on `images['images'][country_name]` with nil value should caused the above exception

Comment: ah I see, so is there a way I can add like a thernary operation to skip that empty array or set it ass null?  sorry for many questions but I've been struggling through many days now haha. I will appreciate your support <3

Comment: Booom!! It worked, although I added an `end` at that last if statement and changed `save!` to `create! `since it was marking some error. But other than that it worked! Thanks man <3